# Codeigniter: Back to previous controller including url variable and run the CI validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day!

**Situation**

Let's say I have a URL that looks like this:

*.....index.php/home/edit_something/STR123*

Now, if validation fails, I want to redirect to previous controller together with the url code (STR123) and validation error so the system can retrieve a specific data again.

**Problem**

How am I going to pass the url variable to previous controller and at the same time run the CI validation error?

**Here's my controller:**

```
public function edit_something()
{   
    // some code here...
}

public function save_edit()
{   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('my_string', 'String', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->edit_something(); 
        // back to previous controller (with code STR123) when validation fails
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_begin();

        // some code/query here...

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->trans_commit();

            // some code/query here...

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

in your view :

```
<?php
    if($products){
        $attrib = array('data-toggle' => 'validator', 'role' => 'form');
        echo admin_form_open_multipart("products/edit/" . $product->id, $attrib)
    }
?>
```

in your controller

ProductController.php

```
function edit($id = NULL){
    if($this->form_validation->run('products/add') == false){
    $this->data['error'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('error'));    
    if($id){
            $this->data['products'] = $this->products->getProductById($id);
        }
        $this->load->view('products/edit', $this->data);
    }
}
```

if you dont want to redirect to a controller instead of a view then :

```
redirect('products/edit'.($id ? '/'.id:''));
```

Comment: hi. I'm sorry i didn't include CI validation on my problem. Updated my post and the title.

Comment: which means you want to run the validation on the previous controller if this validation fails?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Home::page_construct(). And what's the value of $meta?

Comment: updated my answer... you cant just trigger the other controller validation i am checking is there any way to do that..

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', array('message' => 'your validation message.'));

redirect(base_url('index.php/home/edit_something/STR123'));
```